# Where to set the path to the protoc to import standards Protocol Buffers

Tags: dart, protocol-buffers, grpc, protoc

Where need I to set the `path` to the `protoc` to get import standards Protocol Buffers (protobuf), like `empty.proto` and `timestamp.proto` in Windows and Dart?

When the `protoc` is ran:

> protoc --dart_out=grpc:lib/src/protos/generated -Iprotos
>   protos/organization.proto
>   --plugin=protoc-gen-dart=D:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\bin\protoc-gen-dart.bat

The following **error** is presented:

> google/protobuf/empty.proto: File not found. organization.proto:
>   Import "google/protobuf/empty.proto" was not found or had errors.
>   organization.proto:14:27: "google.protobuf.Empty" is not defined.

In IntelliJ `Settings` on `Protobuf Support` plugin the `path` is define where standard protos (*.proto) are:

[image]

Additionally this `path` is define in IntelliJ on `Project Structure` \ `Global Libraries`:

[image]

The code `organization.proto` that import `google/protobuf/empty.proto` to use `Empty` class :

```
syntax = "proto3";

package auge.protobuf;

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";

service OrganizationService {

    rpc GetOrganizations (google.protobuf.Empty) returns (OrganizationsResponse) {}
}
```

IntelliJ analyzer recognizes the `import "google/protobuf/empty.proto"` and `Empty` class on IDEA, but `protoc` can not find.

The environment is:

- SO: Windows 7 x64
- protoc: libprotoc 3.6.1
- Dart: 2.2.0-edge

Answer (score 1):

Say you have `/some/path/to/google/protobuf/empty.proto`, you need to pass `--proto_path=/some/path/to/` so protoc can locate it.

Answer (score -1):

use two dot before protobuf folder path

```
<Protobuf Include="..\Proto\protobuf.proto" ProtoRoot="Proto" />
```

Comment: This is in C#/Visual Studio project, nothing related to Dart.